# Comparing date value from DB with date literal

Tags: python, date, adodb

I'm getting a date value out of a DB2 database using ADODB objects.  This date is sometimes set to 1/1/0001.  This is an invalid datetime in SQL Server.  I need to check for this value and set it to a valid SQL Server date (1/1/1900 for example).  The object coming from the ADODB looks to be a `time.struct_time`.  What's the best way get `1/1/0001` as a `time.struct_time` object and check it for equality to the same value coming from the DB2 database?

### EDIT:

So I figured out a bit more of what's going on.  I'd already tried what d0nut suggested, but the comparison still failed.  When printing what `time.strptime('1/1/0001', '%d/%m/%Y')` returns, you get `1/1/2001`, not `1/1/0001`.  When I try to call `time.asctime(timeFromDb2)` (even with valid date values from the DB), I get this exception message: `argument must be 9-item sequence, not time`.  My guess is that the `time` object I'm getting from the DB is invalid, but because the script in question does nothing with it besides pass it on to another ADODB Recordset object connected to SQL Server, everything is working.  Does anyone have any suggestions on where to go from here?  The code that retrieves the date from DB2 and stores it in the SQL Server DB is pasted below.  This has been working for years until today when we started getting a value of `1/1/0001` from DB2.  the `Inventory` and `Coils` objects are both created via a call to `win32com.client.Dispatch("ADODB.Recordset")`

```
self.Inventory.Fields("promised_date").Value   = self.Coils.Fields("csaxdz").Value
```

Comment: I don't think `time.struct_time` can be before 1/1/1970.

Comment: How would I go about verifying the variable's type?  I can add whatever log messages I want to the script.

Comment: I'm confused as to what's going on at this point.  If I add `LogMessage(type(object))`, I get an exception with the message `type object 'time' has no attribute 'strip'`  I guess I've confirmed that I have a `time` object, anyway?  (`LogMessage()` is the logging function in this script, BTW.)

Comment: `LogMessage` only expects a string. You need to call `LogMessage(str(type(object)))`. I think the posted answer may cover your situation -- it seems `stuct_time` handles all years on some systems (it depends on the C library python is compiled with).

Comment: Ok, just to be complete, `LogMessage(str(type(datefromDb2)))` prints `<type 'time'>`

Comment: @agf let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2275/discussion-between-tim-coker-and-agf)

Answer (score 1):

You should either be able to convert it to a string:

```
time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y', badtimeobj)
```

and compare it that way, or

```
try:
    time.asctime(timeFromDb2)
except:
    invalid = True
else:
    invalid = False
```

or the equivalent, if all other dates work in `asctime`.

Comment: Had already planned on going the catch exception route, but REALLY want to know what the hell is going on now...

Comment: Also, these two calls (can't do line returns in comments) `baddate = time.strptime("1/1/0001", "%m/%d/%Y")` and `LogMessage(baddate.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))` result in this exception `'time.struct_time' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Comment: Sorry, try `time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y', badtimeobj)` ... that might work.

Comment: Python interprets `1/1/0001` as `1/1/2001`, so I can't do the string comparison.  Going to have to just catch the exception.  Still confused as to what is going on.  If I do `time.strptime(timeFromDb2, '%m/%d/%Y')`, I get `argument must be 9-item sequence, not time`.  Even on dates that are completely normal.  Somethings screwy about the time object coming from DB2.  I guess it's blind luck that this script ever worked in the first place since anything I try to do with the DB2 date object blows up.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> time.strptime('1/1/0001', '%d/%m/%Y')
time.struct_time(tm_year=1, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

That will get you a struct which you should be able to easily compare.

Comment: This, I just figured out by calling `baddate = time.strptime("1/1/0001", "%m/%d/%Y")` then `LogMessage(time.asctime(baddate))` prints `Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 2001`, which would indicate that agf's first comment was correct.  If I call `LogMessage(time.asctime(datefromDb2))`, I get this exception: `Updating inventory argument must be 9-item sequence, not time`.  Do you know what that means, exactly?